# Connectedness of $S^2$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm taking a real analysis course, as I've said before, and the professor has been teaching a lot of topology.  We don't have a textbook, so I have to use his notes which are very confusing.  One question we have is:

Prove that the sphere $S^2$ is connected using the definition of connectedness.

The definition of connected we have is:
A topological space $X$ is said to be $connected$ if every continuous map from $X$ to a discrete topological space is constant.

So, which discrete topological space should I be choosing to show that $S^2$ is connected?  And then how would I show that $every$ continuous function is constant, as opposed to just choosing some and demonstrating that they are constant?

Comment: Are you allowed to use that each interval is connected?

Comment: To clarify, with your definition, you need to prove that *for every* discrete space $X$, then *every* continuous map $S^2 \to X$ is constant. Anyway, do you the the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: We have the Intermediate Value Theorem stated in this way:

Let $X$ be a connected topological space.  $a$,$b\in X$.  Then a continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ takes every value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **disprove** that every man is mortal, it is enough to exhibit one man, of whom you can prove that he is immortal.  But to **prove** that every man is mortal, it is not enough to consider just one man.  So where you ask "which discrete topological space should I be choosing", the presupposition is erroneous: you can't do it by choosing one.  If you want to show as space is **not** connected, then that might work.

Suppose $f:S^2\to X$ is continuous and $X$ is a discrete topological space.  Pick two points $a,b\in S^2$.  Let $g:[0,1]\to S^2$ be a continuous function such that $g(0)=a$ and $g(1)=b$ (you may need to write a proof that such a function $g$ exists; that's not hard).  The $f\circ g:[0,1]\to X$ is continuous.  Consider the inverse image of $f(a)$ under $f\circ g$, i.e. the set $(f\circ g)^{-1}(f(a))=\{x\in[0,1]: f(g(x))=f(a)\}$.  By continuity and discreteness, that is an open subset of $[0,1]$.  It has a supremum $c$ in $[0,1]$, i.e. $c=\sup\{x\in[0,1]: f(g(x))=f(a)\}$.

See if you can deduce that $f(g(c))=f(a)$.  The inverse-image of every open neighborhood of $f(a)$ under $f\circ g$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$ that contains $c$.  That means $c$ is a member of an open set whose supremum is $c$.  The only point $d$ in $[0,1]$ that is the supremum of an open subset of $[0,1]$ that contains $d$ as a member is $1$.  Hence $c=1$, and we have $f\circ g$ is constant on $[0,1]$.  Hence $f(a)=f(b)$.  This holds regardless of which two points $a,b\in S^2$ were chosen.  Therefore $g$ is constant.